# i can't make selection sort in masm x86

Tags: masm

i try to make selection sort in masm but my source print nothing only shows error phrase
maybe findMin PROC make error however i can't modify that block
would u help me? :(((

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
intArray DWORD - 117, 10, -1231, 2, 5, -11, -16, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1231, 123, 2, 123, 1, -123, 123, 12333, 875, 844, 111
.code
main PROC
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF intArray
    mov esi, 0
    mov edi, 1
    mov eax, 0
outer:
    call findMin
    call swap
    inc esi
    mov edi,esi
    inc edi
loop outer
call printArray
exit
main ENDP

printArray PROC
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF intArray
    mov esi, 0
L1:
    mov eax, intArray[esi * 4]
    call writeInt
    mov al, ' '
    call writeChar
    inc esi
Loop L1
    call crlf
    ret
printArray ENDP

findMin PROC USES esi ecx edi
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF intArray
    sub ecx, esi; dec unnecessary loop count 
inner :
    mov eax, intArray[esi * 4]
    cmp eax, intArray[edi * 4]
    JG tmp
    inc edi
    loop inner
    mov edi, ebx; save min element index to edi
    ret
findMin ENDP

tmp : ; save min element index to ebx and change esi
    mov ebx, edi
    mov esi, edi
    ret

swap PROC
    mov eax, intArray[esi * 4]
    mov ebx, intArray[edi * 4]
    xchg eax, ebx
    mov intArray[esi * 4], eax
    mov intArray[edi * 4], ebx
    ret
swap ENDP

END main
main PROC
```

what i knew `jmp` isn't save return address then, how to return from jmp? 
(i'm sorry everyone , i really bad at eng grammer ;( )

Comment: jmp doesn't mess with any state, just changes what code is executed next, 
if want to return you need either save stuff to the stack, or if you are trying to do it stacklessly to save your execution pointer (eip/rip) in some address... there are some examples here (with more rules and better explanations than I have): http://www.codegurus.be/Programming/riprelativeaddressing_en.htm